# How to handle CTRL V event in MFC CRichEditCtrl

Tags: mfc

I have created sample MFC application with only one rich edit control in it.
I want to handle CTRL V (keyboard paste) event for this edit control.
when I right click and check events in property, I don't see any event which can handle CTRL V.
I tried ENM_PROTECTED but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle Ctrl-V keypress using `Accelerators`, this prevents the default paste behaviour and allows you to `paste` text of your choice into the Rich Edit Control instead.

The following code was tested with an MFC single dialog app with the name `CMFCApplication4Dlg`, but this should give you everything required to get it working in your application.

Here are the steps required below:

In resource.h add:

```
#define IDR_ACCELERATOR1                156
#define ID_RICH_CTRL_V                  1001
```

In .rc file add:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Accelerator
//

IDR_ACCELERATOR1 ACCELERATORS
BEGIN
    "V",            ID_RICH_CTRL_V,         VIRTKEY, CONTROL
END
```

In your dialog header add:

```
HACCEL m_hAccel;
afx_msg void OnRichCtrlV();
virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
```

In your dialog initilization add:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    m_hAccel = LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ACCELERATOR1));
...
```

Add to the following to your `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_RICH_CTRL_V, &CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnRichCtrlV)
```

And the associated method:

```
void CMFCApplication4Dlg::OnRichCtrlV()
{
    // Ctrl V was pressed handle here

    CWnd *hwnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_RICHEDIT21);
    hwnd->SetWindowTextW(L"Overide Pasted Text Here");
}
```

Add the following PreTranslateMessage:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication4Dlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (m_hAccel)
    {
        if (::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd, m_hAccel, pMsg))
        {
            return(TRUE);
        }
    }

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as per my requirement. Other solutions are also working just it does not meet my requirement. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I remember that this controls handles Ctrl+V by itself. So you have to be more precise: What do you want to handle?

If you want to introduce your own code for the Paste you may add a `PreTranslateMessage` Handler to the View or Dialog. You can handle all Keyboard message there before it is handed out to the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion, xMRi.
I have tried it, and it works but still does not solve my exact purpose.
Below is the code that captures CTRL-V messages.

```
BOOL myRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000 &&
        GetKeyState('V') & 0x8000 &&
        GetFocus() == this)
        {
          //process messages here (keys ??) 
        } 
        return CRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After spending hours on Google, I finally found a piece of code.

MFC Cricheditctrl does not let the user override the OnKeyDown function directly. 
It is a protected member, so I have to create my own CrichEditCtrl, which inherits from Cricheditctrl, and then override OnKeyDown.
but I am still unable to handle CTRL V event.

```
class myRichEditCtrl : public CRichEditCtrl //derived from CWnd
{
  //override below function to handle key down event
  // this function is part of CWnd 
  afx_msg void OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);
}
 
void myRichEditCtrl::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
   //process keys here
   if ( (nChar == 'v' ||  nChar == 'V') && (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) <0))
   {
      // still not working nChar value is 17 when I press ctrl V, Why ??
   }
   
   //call default if needed
    CRichEditCtrl::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```